# How to listen on an on-input-valid paper-input property

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements, core-elements

Please consider the following snippet:

```dart
<paper-input floatinglabel required
  id="title"
  class=''
  label="Title"
  value='{{name.title}}'
  validate='^[A-Za-z'\s-]*$'
  error="Only letters are allowed"
  on-input-valid='{{validInputHandler}}'>
</paper-input>

 void validInputHandler() {
    print( 'valid input' );
  }
```

Although the input is valid for a letter, the validInputHandler is not being triggered.

Reading the docs here http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-input

suggest I am on the correct path but the validInputHandler does not prints anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the `input-valid` event was added later and is not yet contained in Dart core-elements (`paper-input` extends `core-input`).

Currently only `input-invalid` is supported in Dart.

See also [Taking total control of PaperInput validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730326) for an example about custom validation.

Comment: Thanks Gunter. I was wondering what could I have been doing wrong.

Comment: core-elements in the GitHub repo are already regenerated which fixed several bugs and missing features (but not yet published). I guess the same will happen for paper-elements. And the of probably new pub packages will be released soon.