# Taking total control of PaperInput validation

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements, core-elements

I'm using *PaperInput* and like the feel. But, is there a way to do the validation using my own logic? For instance, in some cases a pattern match is not enough to determine the error I'd like to display. An example would be I want the *PaperInput* to specify an item which can only be added once, so the validation would do a lookup in some model map and if *input.inputValue* is not present it is valid, otherwise invalid.

```dart
  <paper-input floatingLabel
               id="alias-input"
               validate="{{aliasIsValid}}"
               type="text"
               error="{{aliasError}}"
               label="Person Alias (eg: King, Eldest Son, Mooch, etc.)"
               required
               ></paper-input>
```

So, I would like to be able to implement *bool aliasIsValid()* and set *@observable String aliasError* when validation is invalid. I do not think this is how it works, but is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Polymer.dart <= 0.16.x**

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:core_elements/core_input.dart';

@CustomTag('app-element')

class AppElement extends PolymerElement {
  AppElement.created() : super.created() {}

  void inputHandler(Event e) {
    var inp = ($['custom'] as CoreInput);
    // very simple check - you can check what you want of courxe
    if(inp.inputValue.length < 5) {
      // any text is treated as validation error
      inp.jsElement.callMethod('setCustomValidity', ["Give me more!"]);
    } else {
      // empty message text is interpreted as valid input
      inp.jsElement.callMethod('setCustomValidity', [""]);
    }
  }
}
```

To validate only when the input element loses focus remove `validateImmediately` from the HTML element and use the `on-change` event instead (not tested).

```dart
<paper-input id="custom" on-input="{{inputHandler}}" validateImmediately></paper-input>
```

I added a comment at https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/pull/102 to make this method available directly in Dart with the next update.

The documentation of `<core-input>` states that the HTML5 constraint validation API is supported. For more information see 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer | When I validate against the regex r"[a-zA-Z'\s-]{2,}", the appropriate error is returned the first time vaidation is done, but after, it seems that no more validation is triggered. For instance, if the input is 'Paul' after an error is generated for 'Pa'. 'Pau' generates no error which is correct. If I then enter 'Pau4', no validation error is returned although 4 is not part of the regex.

Comment: Is this related to `setCustomValidity`? How? If you set a RegEx, the element does the validation, with `setCustomValidity` the validation is don by custom code called from the `on-input` event. Maybe you should create a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. With it I was able to work out the issues.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. With it I was able to work out the issues. There is a question regarding the question. I noticed that the question refers to PaperInput, but the response use core_input. My example uses paper_input. When I attempt to pass the inp var in the response to a method in another library for processing, the jsElement cannot be found. I tried to import dart.js, but this did not help. Which library is this jsElement in. If I use the method in the same script as the inp variable there is no problem. But there are similar codes that I would like to refactor where allowed.