# Form validation in Polymer

Tags: forms, validation, input, polymer, required

I have `Polymer` application and I want to check if given inputs are `NOT EMPTY` on form submission. I have some inputs set to `required` but I don't have any way to check if those fields are `NOT EMPTY`. I can only check if given pattern is matched by checking `invalid` attribute but even for `required` fields pattern is `.*`.

Is there any wait to do it? Or is it in beta and this feature has not been implemented yet?

Answer (score 0):

**Polymer.dart <= 0.16.x**

You can set a pattern yourself

```html
<paper-input floatinglabel
  label="Some label"
  value='{{someValue}}'
  pattern="^.+$"
  error="Input required">
</paper-input>
```

Or see 
[Taking total control of PaperInput validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730326)
for complete control of validation.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. Probably you thought about `pattern` attribute not `validate`. There is not such attribute as `validate`. However, even that I've used `pattern` attribute set to `^.+$` I still have to write something into field and remove content to have validation work. Validation doesn't work when just getting `invalid` attribute. There just should be some method like `valid()` that should check if content matches pattern. And if there is `required` attribute should also check at first if the field was filled in.

Comment: You are right, it should be the `pattern` attribute. I'm not sure what you mean by the rest of your comment `validateImmediately` is true by default which should invoke validation without any field input is done. Otherwise see the question/answer linked in my answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work even with `validateImmediately` attribute. Let me describe my problem with more details. I have such HTML code `<paper-input name="name" floatingLabel required validateImmediately pattern="^.*$" label="Name" type="string"></paper-input>`. Now, when I call such line of code from console `document.getElementsByTagName('paper-input')[0].invalid` I get `false` what is not true. I should get `true` because field is empty. If I fill in field and remove that content and execute that line of code again it returns `true`. It seems to be Polymer error.

Comment: You should file a bug then. As a workaround you could assign an initial value like `''` and try if this invokes the validation. Is the value attribute bound to a field? When do you check this? Did have Polymer already time to fully initialize the control?

Comment: I've tried with filling value attribute but it still doesn't work. Ok I will post a bug. However thanks for help :)