# element.setCustomValidity( num message )

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In Darts API, the method

```
element.setCustomValidity(num message)
```

has a number as the argument. I was expecting the type of the message to be a String. Is this an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an issue https://github.com/Polymer/core-input/issues/41

The Dart element uses information from JS comments to generate type annotations and the comment in the JavaScript element contains the wrong type information.

As a workaround you can call the JS function directly:

```dart
void setCustomValidity(CoreInput inp, String message) {
  inp.jsElement.callMethod('setCustomValidity', ["Give me more!"]);
}
```

see also [Taking total control of PaperInput validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730326)